# Fullalendar language

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar, lang

How can I change full-calendar language to French in Laravel

here are mu cdns :

```
            <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale). If something doesn't work, come back with your code and the specific problem

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ (or so it would appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please try to provide a little more info. Have you already tried something that didn't work, why did it not work, format the codesnip properly etc. etc.

Have a look here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale - It clearly states in the documentation how you can do it.

Comment: Then you are not doing it right. The documentation does not lie. Update your original question with what you have tried and any errors you got.